# Is there a way to independently task and use heterogenous multi gpus in a windows 7 system?

Tags: graphics, opencl, gpgpu, multi-gpu

Can I have two mixed chipset/generation AMD gpus in my desktop; a 6950 and 4870, and dedicate one gpu (4870) for opencl/gpgpu purposes only, eliminating the device from video output or display driving consideration by the OS, allowing the 4870 to essentially remain in a deep sleep or appear ejected/disabled until it's stream processors are called upon?

Compared to the 4870, the 6950 is a heavyweight in opencl calculations; enough so that it can crunch numbers and still allow an active user session, and even web browsing.  HOWEVER, as soon as I navigate to a webpage with embedded flash video, forget what I have running and open media player or media center- basically any gpu-accelerated video task that requires the 6950 to initialize UVD, the display system hangs.

I'm looking for a way to plug my 4870 in an open pcie slot, have it sit in a dormant state with near-0 heat production and power consumption (essentially only maintain the interface signalling, like an ethernet card in a powered-off desktop maintaining the line and waiting for a WOL command), and attain a D0 state (I don't even care if the latency of this wake event is on the scale of seconds) to then run opencl calculations ON ITS OWN.  I do not wish to achieve a non-CF heterogeneous gpu teaming setup!  In my example of a  UVD hung situation I would see manually stopping the opencl calculations on the 6950, beginning those calculations then on the 4870 to free up the 6950 for multimedia usage/gaming as my desire outcome (granted, with a hit to the calculation rate).  Even better if the two gpus could independently run similar calculations while no one is using the desktop.  I don't even mind if I have to initiate the power-state transitions of the 4870 from/into an 'OFF' state (say, by a shortcut on the desktop), as long as it doesn't require a system restart, ending the user session and logging off... and the manual ON/OFF 'switch' for the 4870 is something any proficient windows end-user could do- like click a shortcut to run a script, or even go into device manage and toggle enable/disable.  As long as the 4870 isn't wastefully idling by for 1 sole use that may occur sporadically.

I couldn't think of a solution to facilitate this function besides writing a new ini for the 4870 to override the typical power management characteristics written for usage of the device as a typical graphics card (say to drop in/out of powered state w/o relinquishing irq or other allocated resources to 'hold the door open' on interface availability and addressing).  But that is an endeavor that is both well above my abilities, and I easily see an additional involvement of licensing being necessitated to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 (and maybe windows 10) doesn't define a "selected device". It's softwares' own responsibility to pick the right device. For example, google chrome's add-on software(for video decode) will pick whatever gpu comes as first target defined in it. If it is written to pick first-indexed device, then it needs a pci-e re-plug of both cards to switch their roles.

This OS written to fit for majority(%99) of users, not for multi-gpu users(%1 ?). It simply picks one of gpus or software has explicit control over devices and simply benchmarks all gpus and picks fastest. So you should look for software's abilities instead of OS.

Same thing goes for games too! When I play dota-2 on vulkan api, it uses HD7870 for compute(of textures, particles, etc..) but uses R7-240 for graphics! But I prefer the opposite because R7-240 can't draw fast. Because this game is written for majority of people who don't have more than 1 gpu.

Money controls development I'm sorry for this. Then, market-penetration is needed for money. %99 market penetration needs writing code for public, not scientific guys or rich ones. Public has simply 1 gpu and that is a cheap one.

I wish this:

- select 1 gpu for: unzipping files, wathing videos, compressing internet uploads and caching for file system(up to 2GB)
- select another gpu for: gaming, opencl applications, mining, ..
- select all gpus for: games, benchmarks, seen as single device by my applications,..

but is not guaranteed to become true because money still talks.

If I were a driver developer, I would add a "rename" option(and become poor in return) to give N virtual devices to OS, so OS and other software will be able to gain only 1/N 'th power of whole system or N/N by just using those renames or main devices. A rename could be a single compute unit of a gpu. When OS tells drivers "give me %25 of all cores that share same memory" so it pick a device and gives %25 of total cores of system. So even users could create renames for their own work.

I even sent a message to microsoft for "file system cache on my 2nd graphics card" but they did not return!